# Specifying which ethernet port for apt to use

Tags: apt

I'm trying to perform an update using the normal sudo apt-get update. However my main ethernet does not have access to the outside world (long story I think I purposely did this and forgot how I did it to undo it). I have another network card in there that I plug in for just to get internet. When I ping using the second network card I can ping www.google.com and with the first I can not. So after that long story, apt-get will only try to use the first network card and fail to get a reply back from the internet. I was wondering if there was a way to force apt-get to use a certain eth to retrieve updates?

Comment: Also please note I can not take the first eth down because it is used in a bridge to virtual machines

Comment: in terminal enter route, then post the values here or just tell us which interface is used for "default", this is the default gateway if it shows eth0 it's wrong if it's eth1 it's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the default gateway does not point to eth1 (or what is used for internet) enter this in the terminal:

`sudo route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev eth1`

where the x's are your gateway, your router at home or if you only have a modem the gateway designated by your internet service provider